# Passing authentication token to HTML pages

Tags: html, node.js

I have a user authentication system that generates an access token upon successful authentication. I need to pass this token to other pages as the header parameter to allow usage of that page.

```
    module.exports.authenticate=function(req,res){
        var email=req.body.email;
        var password=req.body.password;
       
       
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM org WHERE email = ?',[email], function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) {
              res.json({
                status:false,
                message:'query error'
                })
          }else{
           
            if(results.length >0){
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, results[0].password)){
                  
                  var access_token = jwt.sign({ id: email }, 'secretpassword123', {expiresIn: 3600});
                  var decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, 'secretpassword123');
                  var expires_in = decoded.exp-decoded.iat;
                  var token_type = "org";
                  console.log(decoded);
                  req.headers.access_token = access_token;
                  res.cookie('access-token', access_token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600)})
              
res.status(200).send({ auth: true, access_token: access_token, expires_in, token_type});
               }
                else{
                    res.json({
                      status:false,
                      message:"Email or password does not match"
                     });
                }
              
            }
    
            else{
              connection.query('SELECT * FROM client WHERE email = ?',[email], function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                  res.json({
                    status:false,
                    message:'query error'
                  })
                }else{
                  if(results.length >0){
                    if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, results[0].password)){
                      var access_token = jwt.sign({ id: email }, 'secretpassword123', {expiresIn: 3600});
                      var decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, 'secretpassword123');
                      var expires_in = decoded.exp-decoded.iat;
                      var token_type = "client";
                      //res.status(200).send({ auth: true, access_token: access_token, expires_in, token_type});
                      connection.query('UPDATE client SET fingerprint = ?', access_token, function(error, results, fields){
                                if(error){
                                    console.log(error);
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log(results);
                                }
                            })
                      return res.redirect('/dashboard.html');
                    }
                    else{
                      res.json({
                        status:false,
                        message:"Email and password does not match"
                      });
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                    res.json({
                      status:false,    
                      message:"Email does not exist"
                    });
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });}
```

I want to pass the `access-token` to other pages and controllers as a way to authorize.

For example, this is my get-user controller:

```
module.exports.getUser = function(req,res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    req.headers.access_token = authenticate.authenticate.access_token
    connection.query('SELECT clientid, email, orgid, name, phone, type, role, fingerprint, verified FROM client WHERE email = ?', req.body.email, function(error,results, fields){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    res.redirect('/dashboard.html');
                }
                else{
                    console.log(req.headers)
                    console.log(results)
                    //res.redirect('/dashboard.html');
                    res.status(200).send(results);
                }
            })
}
```

How should I approach this?

I have added `res.cookie` to the authentication module, and I can see that the cookie gets stored in the browser. But when I try to read the cookie in another page with `req.cookies` or `req.signedCookies` it says undefined.

I ended up using localStorage to store the tokens. This is obviously not secure by oAuth standards, but it works. How can I use cookies to get the same functionality as local storage. I need to use the token generated in the authentication module to verify authorization in other pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually achieved using cookies. After a cookie is set, it will be attached to every request the browser makes to the server. E.g. if you're using a framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie), you could do something like

`res.cookie('access-token', access_token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 300000), httpOnly: true })`

But actually this is just a convenience method to add the "Set-Cookie"-HTTP-Header to your response, which causes the browser to create a cookie: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Btw, for security reasons you should probably set the 'Secure' and the 'HttpOnly' flags, which make sure, that the cookie is only sent using TLS (HTTPS) and cannot be read by JavaScript respectively. The 'SameSite'-Directive is also useful for preventing [CSRF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSRF) attacks.

Comment: How shall I set these flags? Also, since I need to read the token in my JavaScript controllers, how can I pass them so? If that's not possible, should I have the token authorization in the HTML files?

Comment: How the flags are set depends on the server side framework you're using (I've given you an example with expressJs setting the httpOnly flag).
If you're reading the cookie using JavaScript, you mustn't set the httpOnly flag and then read the cookie in JavaScript (e.g. in your controller) using `document.cookie`, which returns a semicolon separated string with all your cookies for your current domain. Alternatively there are some convenience js libs for reading and writing cookies using JavaScript like js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: It's much more clear now. So if I put the path of the authentication controller in the document.cookie reference in another controller, then will it reference to authentication controller. Can I use this to extract the token from authentication then?

Comment: The cookie path determines where your cookie is valid/visible. If you ignore it, your cookie will be set for the entire domain.

Comment: I added the res.cookie method in my authentication controller, but when I check for cookies in another controller, it shows undefined. I have shown my progress in the git repo linked above. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning SameSite!